# Can we wrap an Exception with its own in java

Tags: java, exception

Can I create a Exception like

```
A a = new A (new B ( new A ) );
```

where `A` and `B` are two different type of Exception.

I know Java can do it but is it right to do that ?

Edit : I am writing an retry on type of Exception so I am checking the getCause of the Exception. I am breaking when getCause is null or getCause equal itself , Should I also break when getCause equals any Exception seen so far

Comment: My eyes hurt to see that code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the effect you are trying to achieve? ie: give a context where you'd like to do this

Comment: does that break any Java conventions ?

Comment: I am writing an retry on type of Exception so I am checking the getCause of the Exception. I am breaking when getCause is null or getCause equal itself , Should I also break when getCause equals any Exception seen so far ?

Comment: Why would you create an Exception by using `MyException e = new MyException`? Just `throw new MyException(...)`. Also, why would you need an `Exception` inside another `Exception`?

Comment: You may not be solving your actual problem. Post the code where you are processing your exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> AException a = new AException (new BException ( new AException ) );

This is legal.

---

You can also initialize the cause directly using the `initCause(Throwable)` method.

If you try to make exception its own cause; e.g.

```
 AException a = new AException();
 a.initCause(a);
```

you will get an `IllegalArgumentException("Self-causation not permitted")`.  (Thanks to Joachim Sauer for pointing that out.)

While, the JVM will not stop you creating an indirect cycle, it is a **really bad idea** nonetheless.

- It is an abuse of the `Throwable` API.  It makes no logical sense for an exceptional event to have caused itself, directly or indirectly.
- There is likely be code out there that *assumes* that the "cause" chain of an exception doesn't have any cycles.  Such code is likely to fail in a nasty way if it ever encounters a pathological exception with a cause cycle.

Note that current generation (Java 7) `printStackTrace()` detects and deals with a "cause" cycles, but earlier generations did not:

- http://srl.cs.berkeley.edu/~mhn/ftp/java/lang/Throwable.java.html
- http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java.lang/Throwable.java.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have following classes.

```
public static class A extends Exception {
    public A() {}
    public A(Exception e) {}

}
public static class B extends Exception {
    public B(Exception e) {}
    public B() {}
}
```

Now if you see there is always end to wrapped exceptions when you appears at default constructor. Until then you should call `getCause()`

```
 throw new B(new A(new B()));//Ends with B since no exception is wrapped inside it.
```

Comment: Yes I agree but Is it breaking some rule of Java ?

Comment: @Arjit - no.  See the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

That needs three slightly different answers:

1. **Yes**, you can wrap an exception in another exception of the *same type*.
2. **No**, you can't wrap an exception in *itself* (i.e. in the exact same instance).
3. Unfortunately **yes**, you can create a loop (A causing B causing A causing B ...).

The first one is pretty clear: you can wrap an `IllegalStateException` wrapping an `IllegalArgumentException` caused by another `IllegalStateException`.

The second one is prevented by the code in `initClause()` (which is called by the constructor or can be called directly if it was never called before), that prevents self-causation (indeed `cause == this` is used as a flag that no cause was set, to distinguish it from `cause == null` which means the cause was explicitly set to `null`).

The third bit is bad, but shouldn't happen too often in practice, as you'd have to do some extra work to get it:

```
Exception e1 = new Exception();
Exception e2 = new Exception(e1);
e1.initCause(e2);
```

Luckily `printStackTrace()` actually handles that case:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception
    at ScratchMain.main(ScratchMain.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
    at ScratchMain.main(ScratchMain.java:5)
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception]
```